# Input message not working with submitter value

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the code below in Jenkins pipeline and the submitter field is not accepting list value. Please help me with a solution.

```
withEnv(["app_team_name=${app_team_name}"]){
    sh 'curl -k -u usr:pwd "https://host:port/cli/team/info?team=$app_team_name" > uDeployApp_Team_Name.json'
}
                
def list_team = []
def uDeployJsonData1 = readJSON file:'uDeployApp_Team_Name.json'
                               
for(i = 0; i < uDeployJsonData1.roleMappings.size(); i++)
{
    if (uDeployJsonData1.roleMappings[i].role.name == 'Developer')
    {
        list_team.add(uDeployJsonData1.roleMappings[i].group.name)
    }
}
                 
echo "Value for Control: ${list_team}"
              
Deploy_Env = input message: 'Deployment', 
parameters: [choice(name:'Deployment', choices: ['DEV1', 'DEV2'], description: 'Select Correct UDeploy Environment For Deployment')],
                    submitter: list_team,
                    submitterParameter: 'Approver'
                           
echo "Selected Deployment Environment: ${Deploy_Env}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) for the `submitter` value it states that:

> User IDs and/or external group names of person or people permitted to respond to the input, separated by ','. Spaces will be trimmed.

Therefore you must convert your list into a comma separated list.
something like:

```
 Deploy_Env = input message: 'Deployment', 
              parameters: [choice(name:'Deployment', choices: ['DEV1', 'DEV2'], description: 'Select Correct UDeploy Environment For Deployment')],
              submitter: list_team.join(','),
              submitterParameter: 'Approver'
```

Comment: Thank you for response. It was throwing error, modified as below and it works.

def team_name = list_team.join(",")

Deploy_Env = input message: 'Deployment', 
             parameters: [choice(name:'Deployment', choices: ['DEV1', 'DEV2'], description: 'Select Correct UDeploy Environment For Deployment')],
    submitter: team_name,
    submitterParameter: 'Approver'

Comment: @Varun It is exactly the same code, which exception did you get?

Comment: @ Noam. I just tried, it is working fine. Thank you for help.  Sorry looks like some other issue other day when I ran

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Noam.

Just did below and it worked.

Thank you for response. It was throwing error, modified as below and it works.

```
def team_name = list_team.join(",")

Deploy_Env = input message: 'Deployment', 
             parameters: [choice(name:'Deployment', choices: ['DEV1', 'DEV2'], description: 'Select Correct UDeploy Environment For Deployment')],
             submitter: team_name,
             submitterParameter: 'Approver'
```